# How to ask / vote for a tag synonym to be removed?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I would like a tag synonym to be removed.

Specifically, this is for `svn`  - there is a synonym `svnserve`

`svnserve` is not a synonym for `svn`. While `subversion` of course is, `svnserve` is a way to serve SVN repos - `svnserve allows access to Subversion repositories using Subversion's custom network protocol.`

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnserve.html

It doesn't make sense to have `svnserve` as synonym for `svn` and also `svnserve` should exist as a separate tag.

Comment: I think you just did.

Comment: Er, I think once the synonym is gone, so is the original tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removed the synonym, recreated the tag, added it to the first ten search hits, and gave it a little [wiki love](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/svnserve/info).

Please feel free to update questions with the tag and make the tag wiki better.

Comment: That was quick. Great!

Comment: The question still remains - How to ask/vote for a tag synonym to be removed?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost go read the question again, then the answer.  Then think about what happened to the synonym.  Then repeat this process yourself.