# Remove synonym for RazorEngine to Razor?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I looked at: [How to ask / vote for a tag synonym to be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104326/how-to-ask-vote-for-a-tag-synonym-to-be-removed)

However, either I cannot [intuitively figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/razor/synonyms), I don't have access (11k rep?) or it doesn't exist.

I'm trying to create a new tag for [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) which is independent of [ASP.Net Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-(razor)-faq), as the RazorEngine does not require ASP.Net to function.

I see [razorengine](/questions/tagged/razorengine) is a synonym for [razor](/questions/tagged/razor), so how do I remove it as a synonym? I'd like to tag [Using-Statement in RazorEngine (without the HtmlHelper from MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047024/using-statement-in-razorengine-without-the-htmlhelper-from-mvc/18048690#18048690) with [razorengine](/questions/tagged/razorengine).

I'd probably update the [razor](/questions/tagged/razor) to:

> Razor is a template language that supports seamless transitions between HTML markup and C# or VB code. Transitions between markup and code are indicated by the "@" sign. It is used by ASP.NET Web Pages and ASP.NET MVC (since version 3), but does not require ASP.NET.

and for [razorengine](/questions/tagged/razorengine), probably:

> RazorEngine is a parsing engine that allows robust templates using Razor syntax (independent of ASP.NET).

Comment: We wouldn't want people to accidentally try shaving with an engine, would we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knocked out the synonym and retagged your question.  You may want to suggest a tag wiki for this new tag so the community doesn't take it out again and it can stand on its own.